# "R for Data Science" book (Wickham) . Cannot reproduce example

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am following H. Wickham's **R for Data Science**  and could not make snippet of code from that book work.
I refer to [this](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-order) section and the following graph of the book. 
 [image: plot] .

I literally copied and pasted the part of the code from the book, but it does not work as expected.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

by_age <-  gss_cat %>%
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  group_by(age, marital) %>%
  count() %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, color = marital)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)
```

And even if I use `ungroup() %>%` right before `mutate()` it plots something but not what is in the book (slightly different pattern).

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain this paradox.

The main issue is that `prop` are all equal to 1 in my case. As a result, I get just a horizontal line on the plot.

Thank you!

`tidyverse` version: 1.1.1 
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: Works for me. What versions of the packages are you using?

Comment: Well, what are you getting? Try running `tidyverse_update()`

Comment: > packageVersion("tidyverse")
‘1.1.1’

Comment: Unfortunately, tidyverse_update() did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be a rather simple issue with the code. Yes, it should probably be fixed by Hadley and co but its not a big deal.

If you start by printing `by_age` in the console you should see:

```
# A tibble: 351 x 4
# Groups:   age, marital [351]
```

So, the tibble is grouped by both `age` and `marital`. This means that both `count()` and the subsequent `sum(n)` (within the `mutate`) return the same value since `sum` is only being calculated over the group with only one value i.e. `sum(n) == n` --> `prop === 1`.

You were on the right track with an `ungroup()` however, the desired calculation is the proportion of each marital status for each age. So, add a `group(age)` between the `count` and `mutate` and you are golden.

```
by_age <-  gss_cat %>%
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  group_by(age, marital) %>%
  count() %>%
  group(age) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, color = marital)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Results in:

[image: result]